# How to pd.GroupBy and pd.Cut in the same result?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have this type of DataFrame, containing day of purchase, month, ID and price:

```py
day month       ID      price   
0   1   9       62465   66  
1   1   9       121890  129 
2   1   10      228506  183 
3   1   10      233305  62  
4   2   11      58733   62  
5   2   11      203798  62  
6   3   9       19554   109 
7   3   9       138410  62  
8   3   10      51289   134
9   3   10      261733  62  
.   .   .
.   .   .
```

I need to group values in the dataframe by day ranges from `[1-10] [11-20] [21-31]` and by month.

So I tried to use `pd.GroupBy` with the `pd.Cut` function :

```py
bins = [0, 10, 21, np.inf]
labels = ['1-10','11-20','21-31']
     
data = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['day'], bins=bins, 
                                    labels=labels))['ID'].apply(list).reset_index(name = 'ID')
```

and I got grouping only by day:

```py
    day   ID
   1-10  [62465, 121890, 228506, 233305, 58733, 203798,...
  11-20  [262525, 230997, 259564, 148321, 230887, 26226...
  21-31  [280783, 123942, 84383, 47202, 121890, 229507,...
```

And I struggled with `groupby` function, and how to combine it so I will have the output like this:

```py
 month   day   ID
     9  1-10  [62465, 121890, 228506, 233305, 58733, 203798,...
     9 11-20  [262525, 230997, 259564, 148321, 230887, 26226...
     9 21-31  [280783, 123942, 84383, 47202, 121890, 229507,...
    10  1-10  ................................................
    .     .   ................................................
    .     .   ................................................
    11 21-31  ................................................
```

Comment: try: ```df.groupby([df['month'], pd.cut(df['day'], bins=bins, labels=labels)])['ID'].apply(list)```